# ¿Qué valores de configuración prevalecen?

Tags: laravel-5

Hay unos valores de configuración general seteados en el fichero **".env"** que se configuran a su vez en **"config/app.php"**, por ejemplo:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

en el primero, y:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', TRUE),
```

en el segundo.

Creo que **.env** es un fichero de configuración general de proyecto, a completar al inicio, y no debe tocarse en adelante por lo que existen los valores en el segundo fichero, ¿es correcto? ¿más sobre el tema?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel toma el valor del archivo de configuración **"config/app.php"**

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', TRUE),
```

Y **"app.php"** toma el valor del archivo de entorno **".ENV"**

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

La secuencia en **"app.php"** sería: `'debug'` tiene el valor que hay en `'APP_DEBUG'` del archivo de entorno **".ENV"** y si no lo encuentra tiene `TRUE`.

En el caso que nos ocupa `'debug'` tendría el valor `true`.

El archivo de entorno .ENV no se tiene que distribuir; es diferente en producción y en desarrollo.

[**De la documentación oficial de Laravel 5.5 en español:**](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration)

**Configuración del entorno**

A menudo es útil tener diferentes valores de configuración basados en el entorno donde se ejecute la aplicación. Por ejemplo, usted puede desear utilizar un majeador de cache diferente local diferente que el que se utiliza en su servidor de producción.

Para hacer esto más fácil, Laravel utiliza la librería de PHP DotEnv de Vance Lucas. En una instalación nueva de Laravel, el directorio raíz de la aplicación contendrá un archivo  `.env.example.` Si usted instala Laravel través de Composer, este archivo automáticamente será renombrado como `.env`. De lo contrario, usted debe renombrarlo manualmente.

Su fichero `.env` no debería ser incorporado al control de versiones de su aplicación, pues cada desarrollador / servidor que utiliza la aplicación podría requerir una configuración de entorno diferente. Además, esto supondría un riesgo de seguridad en caso de que un intruso acceda a su repositorio de control de versiones, ya que cualquier credencial sensible quedaría expuesta.

Si usted está desarrollando con un equipo, puede continuar incluyendo un archivo  `.env.example` con su aplicación. Estableciendo valores de ejemplo en el archivo de configuración de ejemplo, otros desarrolladores en su equipo pueden ver claramente que variables de entorno son necesarias para ejecutar su aplicación. Usted también puede crear un archivo `.env.testing`. Este archivo reemplazará el `.env` al ejecutar los tests de PHPUnit o ejecutar los comandos de Artisan con la opción `--env=testing`.

> Cualquier variable en su archivo .env puede ser reemplazada por
>   variables de entorno externas a nivel de servidor o de sistema.

**Obtener la configuración del entorno**

Todas las variables listadas en este archivo se cargarán en la variable super-global de PHP  `$_ENV` cada vez que la aplicación reciba una petición. Sin embargo, usted puede utilizar el helper `env` para recuperar valores de esas variables en sus archivos de configuración. De hecho, si revisa los archivos de configuración de Laravel, puede observar que varias de las opciones ya usan este helper:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

El segundo valor pasado a la función `env` es el "valor por defecto". Este valor será usado si no existe ninguna variable de entorno para la clave dada.

**Determinando el entorno actual**

El entorno actual de la aplicación es determinado a través de la variable `APP_ENV` dede el archivo `.env`. Usted puede acceder a este valor mediante el método environment en la facade `App`:

```
$environment = App::environment();
```

También puede pasar argumentos al método `environment` para comprobar si hay coincidencia en el entorno para un valor dado. El método retornará `true` si el entorno tiene coincidencia con alguno de los valores dados:

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // The environment is local
}

if (App::environment(['local', 'staging'])) {
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
}
```

> La detección del entorno de la aplicación actual puede ser anulada por
>   una variable de entorno `APP_ENV` a nivel de servidor. Esto puede ser
>   útil cuando necesite compartir la misma aplicación para diferentes
>   entornos de configuración, de modo que se puede configurar un host
>   para que coincida con un entorno dado en las configuraciones en su
>   servidor.

**Acceso a valores de configuración**

Usted puede acceder fácilmente a los valores de configuración utilizando el helper global  `config` desde cualquier lugar de la aplicación. Los valores de configuración pueden ser accedidos mediante una sintaxis de "punto", que incluye el nombre del archivo y la opción a la que se desea acceder. Se puede especificar un valor por defecto y será devuelto si la opción de configuración no existe:

```
$value = config('app.timezone');
```

Para establecer valores de configuración en tiempo de ejecución, pasa una matríz al helper `config`:

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

Comment: Si lo he entendido correctamente: se usa el valor del archivo de entorno ".ENV", y se establece el valor 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', TRUE), en "config/app.php", por si el primero no estuviera, pero estando ambos el que se usa es el primero, ¿no?

Comment: Entiendo que és así.