# Quitar la barra de depuración

Tags: laravel-5

Seguro que conoceis este comando: **composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar –dev**

Sirve para crear una barra de debug con la que comprobar que sucede en el programa y revisar si algo falla.

Sin embargo, en la actualidad es un engorro para los visitantes de mi página web. ¿Como la quito?

Comment: Hace tiempo pregunte sobre la **configuración del debug**: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115947. Esto permite "desconectar" la barra. Como usaste composer para instalarla, puedes optar por quitarla de igual modo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562, creo que en este sentido no tienes más opción. Yo habitualmente la incluyo en el "composer.json" y como dependencia  en el fichero "config/app.php" (en providers) y suelo desactivarla comentando la línea en cuestión, es una opción para quitarla tanto en producción como en desarrollo teniendo la opción de reactivarla fácilmente.

Answer (score 2):

En tu archivo `.ENV`; deberías encontrar la siguiente línea

```
APP_DEBUG = true
```

Basta con que la coloques en `false` para que al momento de pasar de modo desarrollo a modo producción deje de mostrar dicha herramienta; así

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Comment: He hecho lo que dices, pero igualmente sigue mostrandose la barra de debug.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he arreglado.
He tenido que irme al fichero config/App.php y escribir lo siguiente:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false)
```

Comment: recuerda que si tu respuesta resuelve la pregunta, la deberías marcar como aceptada así otros usuarios la podrán consultar y de paso generarte mas reputación

Comment: @Alfredo Estoy obligado a esperarme un par de días para poder hacer eso.